# Are there disadvantages bypassing DBSet when calling Find,Add,Update etc. on the context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-3.1

Are there disadvantages bypassing DBSet when calling Find,Add,Update etc. on the context?

creating or getting the DBSet should cost some time. And as far as I know, the Add, Update, Remove methods only set the entity's EntityState to Added,Modified,Deleted and do nothing else. The real action will be performend when calling SaveChanges(Async). 
So the question remains: Is it good to omit the DbSet if possible? see first examples.

calling

```
dbContext.Find(typeof(TEntity), id);
dbContext.Add(entity);
dbContext.Update(entity);
dbContext.Remove(entity);
...
```

instead of

```
dbContext.Set<TEntity>.Find(id);
dbContext.Set<TEntity>.Add(entity);
dbContext.Set<TEntity>.Update(entity);
dbContext.Set<TEntity>.Remove(entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

Subsequent calls of `Set<TEntity>` method are cheap because of results caching. The first call also not so expensive comparing to whole EF overhead.

`Set<TEntity>` returns `InternalDbSet<TEntity>`, whose `Add`, `Update`, etc just redirect calls to set's context.

As a result, there's no any significant differece.

For reference, see:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/DbContext.cs
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/master/src/EFCore/Internal/InternalDbSet.cs